# Extending RestfulController for a base SubClassRestfulController is not working on grails 3.0.4

Tags: rest, grails, controller

[According to Extending Restful Controller](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#extendingRestfulController)

I Can create a SubClass of this RestfulController to become a Base controller class for every rest Controller I want.

Its OK subclassing this to a DIRECT resource controller.

```
Class BooksController extends RestfulController {
BooksController() {super(Book)}
```

But if instead I follow the grails DOC to create a base controller like this:

```
class MyRestController<T> extends RestfulController<T> {
static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
MyRestController(Class<T> domainClass) {this(domainClass, false)}
MyRestController(Class<T> domainClass, boolean readOnly) {
    super(domainClass, readOnly)
}
```

I got an error:

```
Failed to instantiate [clash.MyRestController]: No default constructor found;
```

I tried putting this controller inside controllers folder or src folder.

Only works if I create a default constructor but it is not what I want. I don want this class to serve API for any domain class but instead I want to create new controllers extending this class.

```
class BooksController extends MyRestController {
BooksController() {super(Book)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class is being recognized as a controller and the framework is attempting to create an instance of the controller. One of the criteria we use to identify if that should happen is we check to see if the class is abstract. The class in question should be marked abstract

One way to make it work is to move it out of the `grails-app/controllers` directory and define it under `src/main/groovy/`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. But before I saw your answer I run a grails clean and it started working. Not I'm getting new crazy errors. I'll try to figure out what is going on and maybe I post another question. Thanks

Comment: That surprises me, unless the controller is moved out of the `controllers` folder.

Comment: Adrian, I didnt had to mark the controller class as abstract. The code as it is worked fine. I believe it was a cache problem or something like that. I just put the controller MyRestController in the src/main/groovy folder and extended it using a regular controller . eg. class MyConcreteController extends MyRestController. ** Don't need to put abstract on the class declaration. ** I don't really know why it was not working

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Can you change your answer from mark as abstaract to "  **moved out of the controllers folder** as you commented. I'll mark this as the correct answer because indeed the controller must be out of that folder.

Comment: I don't understand why there might be an objection to making the class `abstract`.  It should in fact be made `abstract` unless you ever want to create one of them directly for some reason, which you shouldn't.

Comment: I agree the controller not used should be abstract. But changing to abstract don't solve the problem. If the controller is inside the controllers folder it raises an error even if it is abstract. To solve the problem the controller need to be out of controllers folder.

Comment: I think that might be a bug, but I can't reproduce it.  I think the code at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/ba15e16a326b00f183521057a1e4ac9aa902019f/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/core/ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java#L106 should be excluding abstract classes.  If you can reproduce it in a sample app, please file a bug at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues.  I may be just missing something.  Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/jeffbrown/abstractcontroller/blob/2d75999f22bf245e591e9c744ea7ea18057fd1ee/grails-app/controllers/demo/MyRestController.groovy#L5

Comment: No @Jeff. I was missing something. Because now starting an app from scracth its running. I tried with your github and created one from scratch. No problem at all. abstract **really solve the problem**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Just clean and run-app solved the problem. My fault