# grails 3.3.9 - extending from restfulController fails with "No default constructor found"

Tags: rest, grails, controller

using grails v3.3.9.

got an error when accessing a restful controller.  grails web shows this

```
URI
/api/device
Class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
Message
Error creating bean with name 'com.softwood.controller.DeviceController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.softwood.controller.DeviceController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.softwood.controller.DeviceController.<init>()
Caused by
com.softwood.controller.DeviceController.<init>()
```

I have setup UrlMapping like this

```
    get "/api/device"(controller:"device", action:"index")
```

my controller extends RestfulController like this, which wont permit a default constructor to be added to the class

```
class DeviceController extends RestfulController<Device> {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    //static scaffold = Device

    DeviceController(Class<Device> device) {
        this(device, false)
    }

    DeviceController(Class<Device> device, boolean readOnly) {
        super(device, readOnly)
    }

    def index (Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        Collection<Device> results = Device.list(sort:"name")
        respond results, deviceCount: Device.count()

    }

    def show (Device device) {
        if(device == null) {
            render status:404
        } else {respond device}
    }
}
```

Theres a link here thats related [Extending RestfulController for a base SubClassRestfulController is not working on grails 3.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173188/extending-restfulcontroller-for-a-base-subclassrestfulcontroller-is-not-working)

however i have cleaned the build, re run etc nothing works.  I get the same failure to instantiate

What is the fix for this to permit extending from RestfulController ?

Comment: PS just create a new test controller and DID not extend from restfulController - setup a new URL mapping and set response formats as json and xml.  when i try and access the new TestController and use 'respond' then i get json response.  Are we not required to use RestfulController any longer?

Comment: "Are we not required to use RestfulController any longer" - You never were required to - I find setting `responseFormats` and using `respond` + gson views sufficient. I almost never want the defaults in `RestfulController` (or you can create your own base controller too)

Comment: "or you can create your own base controller too" - FYI... often, depending on the particulars, the base controller stuff is a good fit to be put in a `trait` instead of a `class`.

Comment: I know this isn't what you are asking about but your `show` action there represents the behavior you would get "for free" if you just use the `show` action that you are inheriting from `RestfulController`.  If the device is found, it will be rendered, otherwise 404.  That is implemented at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.3.9/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy#L65-L72.  You can probably delete your `show` action.

Comment: Also, I probably wouldn't override the `index` action to do what you are doing there.  I would use the default inherited `index` action and override the `listAllResources` method that is defined in `RestfulController`.  That is implemented at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.3.9/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy#L261-L268.

Comment: reason i did the extends because thats what described in the docs for step by step implementation - i was trying to follow what the documentation suggested you can do

Comment: "reason i did the extends because thats what described in the docs for step by step implementation" - I assume you are talking about http://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/REST.html#restControllersStepByStep.  Our docs on step by step implementation there are related to writing controllers that do not extend `RestfulController`.  The code samples show that.

Comment: The very first sentence in that section is "If you don’t want to take advantage of the features provided by the RestfulController super class, then you can implement each HTTP verb yourself manually."

Answer (score 2):

> my controller extends RestfulController like this, which wont permit a
>   default constructor to be added to the class

That is not true. Your constructor should not accept a `Class` as an argument.  You want the no argument constructor.

```
class DeviceController extends RestfulController<Device> {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    DeviceController() {
        super(Device)

        /* If you want it to be read only, use super(Device, true) 
           instead of super(Device)
         */
    }

    // ...
}
```

When Spring creates the controller instance, it is not going to pass anything to the constructor so you need the no-arg constructor.

Comment: jeff - I tried just to provide a no-arg constructor and compiler wont it accept that.  When you hover over the error in intellij it shows "there is no default constructor in class 'grails.rest.RestfullController'

Comment: The way i got round that was to just create a controller that did not extend from RestfulController and that one works.  project is here https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app.   DeviceController wont compile as you have written above - but TestController with no extends seems to work fine

Comment: "I tried just to provide a no-arg constructor and compiler wont it accept that" - That simply is not true.  There is never a case where the compiler prevents a no-arg constructor.  The restrictions related to calling `super(...)` and passing arguments that are consistent with what is in the super class constructor.  A no-arg constructor is always valid and certainly in this case it is. It is the way to use `RestfulController`.

Comment: The controller at https://github.com/jeffbrown/devicesforwilliamwoodman/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/devicesforwilliamwoodman/DeviceController.groovy compiles.

Comment: The docs at http://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/REST.html#extendingRestfulController show using a no-arg constructor.  It is the way to use `RestfulController`.  We designed it that way.

Comment: jeff apologies - i hadnt pushed the last change back to git hub.  have done that just now.  for me the if i add a no arg constructor it wont compile

Comment: jeff i have just attached the screenshot of what i get if i just a no-arg constructor with a constructor  extending from RestfulController - hope you can see that

Comment: hah - spotted what it didnt like - my DeviceController as shown above declared the  no-arg constructor - and it errors - but when you finally get to type the Super(device) as the next line - it starts to compile again.

Comment: Yes.  It wasn't complaining about your no-arg constructor.  It was complaining because you were not calling `super` and if you don't call `super`, the compiler generates a call to `super()` with no arguments for you.  The error was because you were not calling `super` and there is no no-arg constructor in `RestfulController`, so your code was invalid.  It was not invalid because you had a no-arg constructor.  It was invalid because you have an implicit call to `super()`, which relies on a no-arg constructor in the parent class.